# How to measure bandwidth requirements for MySQL, Postgres, …?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

TLTR: how to configure MySQL/Postgres to get a fair measurement of the I/O requirments for analytical queries?

Hello,

for certain database and especially database hardware experiments for want to measure how much bandwidth is required to answer analytical queries (i.e., CHBenCHmark queries on a TPCC data set with a scale of 1000). Current we use iotop to measure the read data from disk for each of the 22 queries. The database is ~80 GBs in size and the VM has 32 GB of main memory (e.g., Postgres reads 14 GB in average for the 22 queries).

Now we want to make fair measurements to get a better idea, what hardware is needed to answer such queries, e.g. answer the average query in less than 10 seconds (i.e., we need 1.4 GB/s bandwidth).

To measure these, we are asking ourselves how to tune the databases best. We don't care about the performance but only the I/O requirements. Right now, we have measured MySQL and Postgres and kept both databases at their default configurations. This includes rather smaller buffers and a huge chunk of OS-based page buffering. We intending to test the same queries with large buffers to see whether there is a substantial difference.

So our main questions are: - is our approach fair to evaluate I/O requirements? - should we tune each database (even though we care about I/O and not performance) or is it acceptable to use defaults? - if we should configure each database, do you have any hints on what to tune towards better I/O performance?

Comment: AIUI, your buffer, no matter how big it is may **or** may not hold the data necessary for your BI queries at any one moment in time. The I/O that you see will vary according to what else is happening on the server. Larger buffers may or may not help initially, but once you start hitting disk I/O limits, that's when the system will slow down.

Comment: For our measurements, there is not other load and there is definitely a lot of buffering going on. That's for sure. But we don't care for performance.

We know there is a lot of I/O. The purpose is to answer: "How much I/O is required to answer a certain query?"

Comment: For MySQL, I'd look at the performance schema.

Comment: We are fine with the I/O results as they reflect the DB-intern numbers.
The question is more whether our measurements are fair at all.

Comment: Compare the performance_schema results with those from iostat - that should give you an idea of buffer I/O v. actual disk I/O.

Comment: We did! The numbers are fine.
My post rather wants to ask if default configurations are fair for such approaches or whether optimized configurations might change the game completely.

Comment: I'm guessing (don't know your RAM, CPU, memory or disk config, nor do I know what queries you're running), but I would imagine that MySQL's default configuration is **not** aimed at DW (data warehouse) type queries. But, for your original question, your bandwidth requirements will depend on how much data you're sending across wire which is easy to determine. In any case, DW queries don't tend to send large amounts of data, the whole point about them is that they are various forms of aggregation and normally present summary data. I think you'll have to be more specific in your questions.